# asp.net file upload inside formview always return false (not in updatepanel)

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, formview

I am using fileupload control inside formview edittemplate

```
    <asp:FileUpload ID="fileup_profilfoto" runat="server" />
      <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Sadece şu formatlar (.jpg, .bmp, .png, .gif)" ValidationExpression="^.*\.(jpg|JPG|png|PNG|bmp|BMP|gif|GIF)$" ControlToValidate="fileup_profilfoto" ForeColor="#00C0CC"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

It was working.But I added an updatepanel then it didnt work,and then I remowed update panel.But it's still return false (hasfile)

```
  protected void frmviewProfil_ItemUpdating(object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            FileUpload fileup_profilfoto = (FileUpload)frmviewProfil.FindControl("fileup_profilfoto");
            if (fileup_profilfoto.HasFile)
            {
                //do something
            }
           else
            {
            //do something
            }
          }
      }
```

always goes else scopes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hi use triggers to achive that

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="conditional">
  <Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
 </Triggers>
 <ContentTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label><br /><br />
   <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
  </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

code behind

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
      {
          Label1.Text = FileUpload1.FileName;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you do anything to the properties of the fileupload control, for example setting the autopost back value to false? Try setting this to true if it is false.

Comment: hey @callum thganks but fileupload control doesnt have autopostback property.And I didnt do any change to the properties of fileupload control.I couldnt believe,it was working.I remowed updatepanel because od this.But I think it wasnt about it

Comment: Hmm strange..this seems like a stupid answer but try closing down and re-opening visual studio, this has been the problem for me in the past.

Comment: hehehe you are right.But your offer is not stupid.Asp.net is stupid.Be sure that I tried,re-open project,even clearing cookies but couldnt solve :) thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question when I had this problem and figured I'd post what my problem and solution were as well.

**Make sure the file you are trying to upload is larger than 0 bytes.** I was trying to upload some blank text files for testing and each file had the `FileName` property set correctly, but `HasFile` was always false. Adding some text to the files gave it some content and the file was able to be uploaded successfully.